# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException during adapter filtering

Tags: java, android, filtering, android-arrayadapter

This part of the code is supposed to filter through the objects in the adapter and remove or add objects in the listview depending on the user input. However when I try to put  in any letter I get an error saying: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5 or similar depending on the input in the EditText. I don't understand what causes this.

Here is the code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import nick.miros.BudgetControl.budgetcontrol.app.Currency;
import nick.miros.BudgetControl.budgetcontrol.app.R;

public class CurrencyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Currency> {
    private final Context context;
    private List<Currency> currencies;
    private CurrencyFilter currencyFilter;

    public CurrencyAdapter(Context context, List<Currency> currencies) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_currency, currencies);
        this.context = context;
        this.currencies = currencies;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_currency, parent, false);

        TextView currencyName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.currencyName);
        TextView currencySymbol = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.currencySymbol);

        currencyName.setText(currencies.get(position).getCurrencyName());
        currencySymbol.setText(currencies.get(position).getSymbol());

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (currencyFilter == null)
            currencyFilter = new CurrencyFilter();

        return currencyFilter;
    }


    private class CurrencyFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = currencies;
                results.count = currencies.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<Currency> nCurrencyList = new ArrayList<Currency>();

                for (Currency c : currencies) {
                    if (c.getCurrencyName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nCurrencyList.add(c);
                }

                results.values = nCurrencyList;
                results.count = nCurrencyList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                currencies = (List<Currency>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output which I get:

```
06-29 23:08:05.369  15570-15570/nick.miros.BudgetControl.budgetcontrol.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
            at nick.miros.BudgetControl.budgetcontrol.helper.CurrencyAdapter.getView(CurrencyAdapter.java:41)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2337)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1289)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1201)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4946)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1433)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:720)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:593)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4946)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:326)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15669)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:872)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:593)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15669)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4946)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:326)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2214)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15669)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2232)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1510)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1206)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

which points to this line:

```
currencyName.setText(currencies.get(position).getCurrencyName());
```

Comment: Ok, found it. I needed to implement the getCount() method within my custom adapter.